# How shall I compute $S(n):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{[n/2]}\frac{\binom{n}{2i}}{2^i\cdot i!}$ ?

Tags: number-theory

I was trying to work out myself on sum of binomial coefficients and then got the following problem. We are given 
$$S(n):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{[n/2]}\frac{\binom{n}{2i}}{2^i\cdot i!}$$ where $[.]$ is the greatest integer function.

Is there any closed sum value for this? It seemed difficult for me to proceed. How shall I proceed ?

Thank you

Comment: No closes form, sorry. Clearly, this is related to [Laguerre polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html)

Comment: :-( my bad !! struggle continues !! :-(